# Legend for Bubblechart

Tags: legending, charts

I am trying to create an easy legend with bubbles for a Bubblechart.

The legend should have the BubbleSizes -> {.02, .05}, for the scores 3 to 8 and ranging with the rainbow colors. Basically this but with bubbles of increasing size, instead of squares: 
[image]

Is there any easy way to do this???

This is my code right now:

```
legend2 = 
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {3, 8}}, 5, 
  LegendLabel -> Style["Happiness Score", 16], LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dt = Range[3, 8];

SwatchLegend[ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[dt], 
  dt, 
  LegendLabel -> Style["Happiness Score", 16], 
  LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, LegendMarkers -> "Bubble", 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 5 dt]
```

[image]

Change the second argument from `dt` to `Rescale[dt, MinMax@dt, {.02, .05}]` to change the labels:

[image]

Comment: Can also use `PointLegend` and omit `LegendMarkers`.

Comment: Is there a way to make the numbers smaller? LegendMarkerSize only changes the size of the bubbles

Comment: @Faye, pls see the new version.

Comment: Now, how did you figure out there is such "Bubble" markers? @kglr ? :)

Comment: @MinHsuanPeng, it is in the docs: [SwatchLegend >> Options >> LegendMarkers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SwatchLegend.html)